# How to create an array with a simple for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need to create an array that looks like this:

> ```
> [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4....]
> ```

Given my following code, how can I eliminate the `counter`?

```
int[] SomeArray = new int[24];
int counter = 0;
for(int x = 0 ; x < SomeArray.length-1 ; x++){
    SomeArray[x] = counter;
    SomeArray{x+1] = counter;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Current code only increase x by one step, so the output should be  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 8+, you could use an [`IntStream.range(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) and `map` each value as desired. Something like,

```
int[] someArray = IntStream.range(0, 24).map(x -> {
    return x / 2;
}).toArray();
```

Also, please follow Java variable naming conventions (`someArray`, not `SomeArray`).

If you have to use Java 7 (or earlier), then you can do it with something like

```
int[] someArray = new int[24];
for (int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    someArray[i] = i / 2;
}
```

Comment: Im using android studio so i need to use Java 6.

Comment: @דודיחיסין Edited. Next time, for better help faster, include relevant details like that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

use increment x=x+2 as two indexes of array are being stored in every iteration

```
for(int x = 0 ; x < SomeArray.length-1 ; x+=2){
        SomeArray[x] = x/2;

        SomeArray[x+1] = x/2;
}
```